# how to inject Oracle JDBC driver dependency from Jboss modules into application pom?

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, jboss, pom.xml

I have created a module in JBoss with Oracle JDBC driver, with this module datasource is configured on Jboss AS7.1.
Can I refer this Jboss module (With OJDBC.jar) into my application `pom.xml` to satisfy Oracle JDBC driver dependency?

[Jboss Module for Oracle driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMwZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.Open jar with 7zip and look file MANIFEST.MF (Implementation-Version) to find version (i think version=11.*.*.*)

2.Install jar in local repository .m2

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 \
     -Dversion=11.*.*.* -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=d:/***/ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.*.*.*</version> 
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Scope =  runtime because you don't use ojdbc-implementation at compilation

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This way we can add dependencies, it worked. But i was looking for some solution in which we may reuse the jboss oracle module which was created to provide ojdbc6.jar to a datasource in Jboss.

Comment: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=350 , but if you want to use it with pom.xml , look my solution

Answer (score 0):

For compile level:

1. Create a entry in your repository for the artifact (.jar);
2. Refers it in your pom.

For runtime level:

1. Add jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

JBoss will add the classes to the class path of the application when it is deployed.